# How can i drop duplicates row from pandas dataframe but just in some range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas Dataframe (70 000 rows) like this:

| No | Time | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.12079 | 60 |
| 2 | 2.581 | 12 |
| 3 | 2.7172 | 60 |
| 4 | 3.43883 | 60 |
| 5 | 3.6883 | 54 |
| 6 | 3.7233 | 54 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 70 000 | 172.2777 | 24 |

In column Time i have values in float type representing time in seconds.  I need to drop rows that has duplicates in length but just in range of 1 second. So my output
should look like this:

| No | Time | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.12079 | 60 |
| 2 | 2.581 | 12 |
| 4 | 3.43883 | 60 |
| 5 | 3.6883 | 54 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why is not Time `3.43883` filtered out? Is within 1 second of `2.7172` ...

Comment: @AndrejKesely Its not in range. I want to delete duplicates from 1.0000s to 2.000s and then 2.000 to 3.000 so when i have in first range 3 rows with length 60 i delete 2 but in next range (2s-3s) i can have this length again about also just once.

Comment: @Ed Kloczko Thanks for your answer, but this option will take very long time or?

Comment: With 70,000 you could probably get a simple looping function to run in a minute or so. With very fancy numba/jit stuff you can probably make it really fast, but might not be worth it.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, i know, but this is what i need.

Comment: @ALollz Its csv output from wireshark. 70 000 rows is just 5 minute of video call. So the dataframe could be much bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you seek?

```
df["int_time"] = df["Time"].astype(int)
print(
    df.groupby(["Length", "int_time"], as_index=False)
    .first()
    .sort_values(by="No")
    .drop(columns="int_time")
)
```

Prints:

```
   Length     No       Time
3      60      1    2.12079
0      12      2    2.58100
4      60      4    3.43883
2      54      5    3.68830
1      24  70000  172.27770
```

Comment: This works fine thanks!        Ďakujem pomohol si mi veľmi, pracujem na bakalárke :D

Answer (score 3):

Since your requirement is

> I want to delete duplicates from 1.0000s to 2.000s and then 2.000 to
> 3.000

Create a temporary column that is the `floor` of your time value (same as `//1`), then drop duplicates with respect to that and the length.

```
df = (df.assign(Time2=df.Time//1)
        .drop_duplicates(['Time2', 'Length'])
        .drop(columns='Time2'))

#       No       Time  Length
#0       1    2.12079      60
#1       2    2.58100      12
#3       4    3.43883      60
#4       5    3.68830      54
#6  70 000  172.27770      24
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm very confused by your example output, but based on your description, and assuming the dataframe is already sorted by time: you could make a new column containing the difference between the time in row x and the time in row x-1:

```
df['Diff'] = df['Time'].diff()
```

Then drop the rows where Diff > 1

```
df['Diff'] = df['Diff'].fillna(999)  # make sure first row doesn't get deleted
df = df[df['Diff'] > 1].drop(['Diff'],axis=1)  # filter and drop the temporary "Diff" column
```

Comment: I think they want to group by `Length`. The rows they're dropping are where there are `Time` values within a second of each other that corrspond to the same `Length` value.